# Thoughts on a mixin requiring a specific HTML structure?

Tags: html, css, sass

I am working on a project that contains some complex mixins. We are using a modified BEM class naming strategy, so a typical mixin looks something like this:

```
@mixin mixin__nestedHeader {
    color: grey;

    &__title {
        font-size: 1.2em;
    }

    &__message {
        font-size: 0.6em;
    }

}
```

And this would style a block of HTML that looks like this:

```
<div class="header">
    <h4 class="header__title">Title Text</h4>
    <div class="header__message">Message Text</div>
</div>
```

So, the problem we are running into, is that the mixin determines what our HTML structure is. On one hand, we want this HTML to always be styled the same since we're using a mixin, so needing it to always be the same is not the end of the world. But, if this HTML code is already nested inside an "item" block, it causes our classes to be "item__headerTitle" and "item__headerMessage" which makes the mixin not work.

Now, we can add the classes using arguments on the mixin, which is what compass does. But, that makes the mixin more complex to use.

I'm wondering what are everyone's thoughts on letting a mixin dictate what HTML structure is used. Do you just deal with it since you're getting the benefit of using the mixin? Or is it something that is a deal-breaker for you which causes you to stay away from more complex mixins that style multiple elements with specific class naming. There are no wrong answers, we are just trying see what people think.

Comment: I think this may be more suited for the CodeReview StackExchange site: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

*TL;DR: With gratuitous code-commenting, I think dictating the structure in the styling is fine. Also, having your mixin accept arguments makes it more flexible to use, but exponentially more complex to build/maintain. Really think hard if you're ok with that tradeoff.*

The nice thing about working in any sort of environment/language that will ultimately be compiled or minified before it gets to production, is that it allows you to be incredibly verbose with your code comments. At best, they can be an incredibly helpful insights into how stuff works. At worst, they are easily ignorable and get stripped when compiling for production anyways, so there really isn't a cost. SASS is no exception.

With that preface in mind...
I have done something similar in the past where we were using [placeholder selectors](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#placeholder_selectors_) as a base style for a particular family of elements that would each get extended with their own unique styles given the situation. The structure of the markup that those elements needed to use, along with how to write and an extended style was all included within that particular SASS include. It ended up looking something like:

```
%full-width-story-block {
/* Can be included with article.story-block elements which need to occupy their container's full width.
   See "Usage" section after the style definitions for notes & examples. */

  flex-basis: 100%;
  display: flex;

  & > * {
    @include make-col(6);
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;
  }
  & > div {
    padding-left: $story-block-spacing*2;
  }
  & > a { display: block; }
  @include media-breakpoint-up(md) {
    h3 { padding-top: 0; }
  }

  @include media-breakpoint-down(sm) {
    flex-wrap: wrap;

    & > div {padding-left:0;}
    & > * {
      @include make-col(12);
    }
  }

/*  Usage :
    + Ensure that the element is rendered on the page in the following pattern:
      (note the div containing everything but the 1st anchor/image tags.
       This is generally not included when story-block elements are used in "Content Walls")

        <article id="post-4321" class="story-block">
            <a href="/link/to/post"> <img src="story-pic.jpg" /> </a>
            <div>
              <h3> <a href="/link/to/post">Story Title</a> </h3>
              <p>A short excerpt from the article...</p>
              <div class="save-article">
                <a class="save-to-pocket" href="/pocket/url"/> <svg>...</svg></a>
                <a class="save-to-instapaper" href="/instapaper/url"/> <svg>...</svg></a>
              </div>
            </div>
        </article>

    + Extend the styling to the element container:
          .container-needing-full-width-story-block {
              .story-block { @extend %full-width-story-block; }
          }
*/
}
```

The big thing was communicating that the info was there and being consistent in the implementation. There were a couple of different families of components that shared that sort of structure, and they each had their required markup structures and process of extension laid out in the code comments in a similar manner. This made it easy for other dev to come along and start using & extending the structures we had already spent time setting up.

Also, the fact that all of this documentation (for a lack of a better word) existed within the codebase itself means that all this knowledge would be ported around with the project files by default. So in 2 years when a fix or update needs to be applied, as long as we have the code-base, we're not trying to track down some obscure internal knowledge-base/wiki article or the devs who originally built it.

All of that being said, I would caution you on writing something that would accept arguments. In theory it does allow for more flexibility in the structure of markup, but that flexibility comes at the cost of increased complexity in building and maintaining that mixin. I've seen/built things like that which had good intentions, but ultimately ended becoming very "switch case"-ey, with each usage of the mixin elsewhere in the project requiring changes to the mixin itself to handle that particular situation's idiosyncrasies. Just something to think about...